# Fix Keypress Repeating Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, listener, keystroke

I have a script that waits for keypresses and logs them in the console:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The system itself works, however, when a key is held down, it produces the following result:

```
Key.space pressed
Key.space pressed
Key.space pressed
Key.space pressed
Key.space pressed
Key.space pressed
Key.space pressed
Key.space pressed
Key.space pressed
```

How can I make the thread pause until the key is released?

Answer (score 0):

This code must help you

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
is_released=False
def on_press(key):
    global is_released
    if is_released:
        print('{0} pressed'.format(key))
        is_released=False

def on_release(key):
    global is_released
    print('{0} release'.format( key))
    is_released=True
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a set to check which key is currently being pressed.

```
pressing_keys_set = set()

def on_press(key):
    if key not in pressing_keys_set:
        print('{0} pressed'.format(key))
        pressing_keys_set.add(key)

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(key))
    pressing_keys_set.remove(key)
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```